# How can I timestamp each line outputted by a serial device?

Tags: gnu-screen, timestamp

I access a serial measurement device via `screen /dev/tty.usbserial 9600`. While the device is measuring it outputs its data *n* times per second on one line. How can I add a timestamp every line (or every few lines, if it slows the log too much)?

I'm on OSX 10.8.2 and use Terminal.app as my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any way to let screen print timestamps. Instead, creating screen's log file and print it with awk works well!

**1. Create (or edit) ~/.screenrc to let screen create a log file.**

Add logging configuration to .screenrc (screen's config file) in your home directory.

```
logfile "/path/to/log/file" # Specify log file name with absolute path.
logfile flush 1
deflog on
```

**2. Start screen**

```
$ screen /dev/tty.usbserial 9600 -L
```

Then screen starts creating a log file.
(There are some other ways to create log files.)

**3. Print the file with tail + awk**

Run this shell command in another terminal window.

```
$ tail -f screen.log | awk '{ print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

It prints the log file with timestamps!

```
15:41:27 xxx
15:41:28 xxx
15:41:29 xxx
15:41:30 xxx
15:41:31 xxx
```

If you want to print the log with timestamps to both standard output and a file, please pipe it to tee command.

```
$ tail -f /path/to/log/file | awk '{print strftime("%H:%M:%S"),$0; fflush();}' | tee /path/to/another/file
```